# Window.location file download

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to download a file to client side using following javascript code:

```
window.location = InsightRoute + "GetOrderXML?orderNumber=" + txtOrderNoVal
```

If the file is available then it will get downloaded to the  client machine. But the issues is if no file is available for downloading, it 
                        will simply gets redirect to a blank page
                        http://mysite/GetOrderXML?orderNumber=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file is not available then use following code inside controller, so that the alert will pop up:

```
Response.Write("<script>alert('Item does not exist on this environment.');window.history.go(-1);</script>");
return null;
```

Use of: *window.history.go(-1);* If there is no file and since it is getting redirected to a new page: *http://mysite/Insight/GetOrderXML?orderNumber=1*, which can be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether the file is available for downloading before redirecting, for example like this:

```js
if (sdpInsightRoute && txtOrderNoVal)
  window.location = sdpInsightRoute + "GetOrderXML?orderNumber=" + txtOrderNoVal
```

This way, if the variable `txtOrderNoVal` is `undefined`, the redirection wouldn't take place.

Comment: This is not possible because :   sdpInsightRoute + "GetOrderXML?orderNumber=" + txtOrderNoVal   this is the call to controller and it is returning the file that needs to be downloaded. When ever I call this  window.location = sdpInsightRoute + "GetOrderXML?orderNumber=" + txtOrderNoVal I am able to download the file to client side but if there is no file I need to show an alert mentioning that "no file is available for downloading" . I don't know how to show alert if there is no file instead of redirecting to a blank page .